# How to restrict/stop angular application loading based on HTTP response

Tags: angular

I have very unique use case for **loading** the angular application. We are targeting to use **single angular build** for multiple domains.

So, before loading the angular app I need to check for domain name whether it exists or not in our system(backend). For that, I am going to call REST API from where I will get the response of domain name existence. If domain exists then http response will be `true` otherwise it will be `false`.

If the response is `false` then the user should be redirected to a static HTML page, stating that domain is not allowed for application loading.

I have followed [this link](https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/). But this solution will still load the application.

I want to totally restrict/stop application loading based on http response. So I need some guidance that, how could I implement solution for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Angular introduce the notion of service & routes

You can use a service to send request & catch the HTTP response (https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Then you can use the route functionnality to redirect people (https://angular.io/guide/router)

You can also update a "Loading" variable in your high level service (app service let's say) and then check/update this value using an Observable / BehaviorSubject